# Windows 7: Merge Front and Back Stereo channels and output the resulting one in the subwoofer channel

Tags: windows-7, audio, stereo

I have a Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium, and I use the standard 5.1 analog outs on the back of said card.

I am playing Elite Dangerous and have a [custom buttkicker gaming chair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuaOE.jpg), but apparently Elite has 5.0 sound, not 5.1, meaning that the basses are encoded in the main front/back channels.

My dedicated amplifier already has a low-pass filter, so all I need to do is feeding it the audio... but at the same time I want to hear it from my surround (analog) headset (a Medusa Speedlink).

Is there any way, software I presume, to combine the output of front+back channels and redirect them on the subwoofer output?

Comment: So... whoever downvoted the question, can I ask what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with similar issues, I have solved the problem with this nice little open-source program called [equalizerapo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/).

The documentation is clean and easy to understand, and I was able to divert all sound channels to the subwoofer out.